# how to create google home app

Tags: actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, google-home, dialogflow-es

I am new to google home. I had an experience in Amazon Alexa custom skill development. In Alexa, I had deployed my codebase in lambda function and also test my custom skill using actual Alexa device register with my email id.

So, Now I need to develop similar skill in google home device. Till now, I didn't get any good tutorials.

Is it possible to create & test Google Home app like Alexa skill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The steps you go through to develop a Google Home action or app are very similar to creating an Alexa skill. There are a couple of differences, but logically they are the same.

- If you use a NLP system such as Dialogflow (which is strongly suggested), you build the suggested phrases that the system responds to and the Intents they correspond to. You would specify your webhook as part of building these phrases. If you don't wish to use an NLP, you can specify the initial Intent phrases using the Actions SDK and specifying the configuration as part of a .json file. Other actions you'd do in the Alexa console are similar to what you'd do in the Assistant console.
- You can deploy your Action on any public server that accepts HTTPS connections. This can include AWS Lambda with an AWS API Gateway trigger, or a Firebase Function, or a web server you more directly control that has a valid SSL certificate. This webhook would get a JSON body and needs to send back a valid JSON response. Google has libraries for node.js to help with this.
- Google has a relatively full-featured simulator which you can use to test your Action. Once it is available in the simulator, it is also immediately available on every device attached to that account. You can permit other accounts to the project as well and, once they have activated it through the simulator, it is available on all their devices as well.

A full set of documentation is available at https://developers.google.com/actions/. It includes links to sample code, and you can find more step-by-step codelabs at https://codelabs.developers.google.com/?cat=Assistant

Answer (score 2):

If you're familiar with how to develop skills for Alexa you might want to check out the [jovo-framework](http://jovo.tech). It makes it pretty easy to create skills that work for both Amazon Alexa and Google Home.

Here is a good starter template and walk-through that will get you going. https://github.com/rmtuckerphx/ask-cli-jovo-starter